# How to retrieve the keys of the json of the first row in postgres in golang?

Tags: json, postgresql, go

I currently have a table like this

```
id | value
----------
1  | {"key1":"value1", "test1":"value3"}
2  | {"key1":"value2", "test1":"value4"}
```

I would like this returned

```
key1, test1
```

The keys are the same in each row, but the number of keys may change.

I tired using

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(value) FROM mn_statistics_company
```

however, that got me all the keys of all the json of that row
    key1
    test1
    key1
    test1

and have tired

```
SELECT value FROM mn_statistics_company LIMIT 1
```

but that just returns the json with both the key and values.

```
{"key1":"value1", "test1":"value3"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT...`, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys(value) FROM mn_statistics_company;
```

See example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7a037/1/0).